# Rails not registering API call variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple API called wrapped in my lib/

```
lib/riotapi.rb

class RiotApi
    riot_url = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=ENV['mykey']'

    def unique_url
        response = HTTParty.get(riot_url)
        json = JSON.parse(response.body)
        json
    end
end
```

my controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

    require 'riotapi'

    def index
        api = RiotApi.new()
        @list = api.unique_url
    end
end
```

I have my welcome#index as the index page of the application. When I open it up, it says that `undefined local variable or method "riot_url"`

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: The above sample is taken from here 
[Very Basic Rails 4.1 API Call using HTTParty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897592/very-basic-rails-4-1-api-call-using-httparty)

Comment: Take a look at the syntax highlighting in your first block. Did you copy/paste that in? Seems like you are missing a `'`

Comment: sorry that was typo on my part, the syntax is all good as far as I checked!

Comment: @AbM interesting, that seem to did the trick! If you'd like to answer this question, I would love to accept your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a ruby constant (ALL CAPITAL) for this:

```
lib/riotapi.rb

class RiotApi
    RIOT_URL = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=ENV['mykey']'

    def unique_url
        response = HTTParty.get(RIOT_URL)
        JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
end
```

Also note that you do not have to use the `json` variable in your `unique_url`

Here's is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7573506/2697183) that goes over the variable scope in a class. Note that I chose a ruby constant since I assumed the url will not changed. If you have a method in your class that changes the url, you should use a class variable (the one with `@@`)

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to the difference between `riot_url` and `RIOT_URL`?